# How to compare two arrays and add the missing elements from the bigger to the shorter in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two arrays:

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array2 = [1, 2, 3]

How can I compare them and add 4 5 into array2?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I created a very dummy example that does what you ask for.

I am sure that you can create a performance-wise better solution, but this code will do the job:

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3];

function compareArraysAndAddMissingItems(a, b) {
  if (a?.length > b?.length) {
    b = [...b, ...a.filter(x => !b.some(y => y === x))];
  } else {
    a = [...a, ...b.filter(x => !a.some(y => y === x))];
  }

  return [a, b];
}

const newArrays = compareArraysAndAddMissingItems(array1, array2);
console.log(newArrays[0], newArrays[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always need to fill the second array from the first, you could do something like this:

```
const fillTheSecond = <T>(a1 : readonly T[], a2: readonly T[]) : readonly T[] => {
    const seen = new Set<T>(a2);
    return a2.concat(a1.filter(item => !seen.has(item)));
}

console.log(fillTheSecond([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]));
```